# Rails4.2 heroku環境でSidekiqにプロセスが入らない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, redis

Heroku環境でmailerをSidekiqで非同期処理したいのです。
キューは入るのですがプロセスが入りません、開発環境ではプロセスも入り非同期処理を行うことが可能です。

ma$ heroku ps
=== web (Free): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: up 2015/07/18 17:47:02 (~ 6m ago)

=== worker (Free): `bundle exec sidekiq -q carrierwave`
worker.1: crashed 2015/07/18 17:46:52 (~ 6m ago)

```
#config/initializers/sidkiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  case Rails.env
    when 'production' then
      config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], namespace: 'sidekiq' }
    when 'staging' then
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://stg.redis-example.com:6379', namespace: 'sidekiq' }
    else
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379', namespace: 'sidekiq' }
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  case Rails.env
    when 'production' then
      config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], namespace: 'sidekiq' }
    when 'staging' then
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://stg.redis-example.com:6379', namespace: 'sidekiq' }
    else
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379', namespace: 'sidekiq' }
  end
end

#Procfile
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml


#sidekiq.yml
:verbose: false

:concurrency:  25
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
  - carrierwave
:daemon: true


#heroku restart後
#heroku logs --tail
2015-07-19T03:48:03.145504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-07-19T03:48:03.199847+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-19T03:48:06.146853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902735+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:06] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902740+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902742+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902745+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902746+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902748+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902749+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902750+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902752+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902754+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902756+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902757+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902759+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902760+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.902762+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903091+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:06] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903167+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903215+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903217+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:10714
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903218+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903220+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-19T03:48:06.903251+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-07-19T03:48:08.219896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-07-19T03:48:08.348078+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`
2015-07-19T03:48:08.776837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 18578 -e production`
2015-07-19T03:48:08.989739+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819431+00:00 app[worker.1]: You really should set a logfile if you're going to daemonize
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819468+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:173:in `daemonize'
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819470+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:41:in `parse'
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819471+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819472+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
2015-07-19T03:48:10.819474+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
2015-07-19T03:48:11.573789+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-07-19T03:48:11.560084+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-19T03:48:21.789930+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-07-19T03:48:21.794994+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=18578
2015-07-19T03:48:21.794295+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-19 03:48:21] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-07-19T03:48:21.959680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: heroku上でworker dynosがONになっていない、もしくは dynos が足りないということはないですか? `heroku ps` の結果を調べてみてください。そのProcfileを見る限り dynos は 4 以上である必要がありそうです。

Comment: heroku psを追加しました。問題ないように思えますがどうでしょうか

Comment: `worker.1: crashed` となってます。`heroku log` にクラッシュの詳細が記録されていると推測されますので、調査してみてください。ああredisのほうも `redis.1: crashed` ってなってますね。redisが動いていないために、sidekiqも動いてないということかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 2015-07-22 22:40 追記 - まとめ

heroku 上ではファイルを作成することができません。
一方 sidekiq はデーモンモードで起動・実行する場合、
ログをファイルに出力する必要があります。
そのため heroku 上では sidekiq をデーモンモードで動かすことはできません。

---

#### 以下、オリジナルの経緯

Procfile から

```
redis: bundle exec redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

の行を削除 or 無効化してから heroku に push してみてください。

ログからは redis-server の起動にポートかぶりで失敗したせいで、他の worker が止められてしまっているように見えます。他の設定状況から考えると、 heroku 上では rediscloud を使うおつもりのようですので、Profile で redis-server を起動する必要は無いはずです。

これだけが原因であると断定はできないのですが、まずは提案まで。問題が続くようであれば、ログを再取得してみてください。

---

#### 2015-07-18 19:35 追記

ログから worker 用の dynos が有功に設定されていないのではないかと考えました。それにより dynos の制限を超えてしまって SIGTERM が送信されることで止まっているのではないか、と推測しています。

念のため worker 用の dynos を https://dashboard.heroku.com/ で確認してみてください。以下の様な状態であれば、workerは1つだけ実行可能です。(実行されるコマンドは私のアプリのものですので、多少異なると思われます)

> [image: worker dynos on(1)]

そうではなく、以下のようになっている場合は worker は利用できないはずです。

> [image: worker dynos off]

その場合、右上のEditを押してプランを変更することで、workerが利用できるようになります。

変更後に `$ heroku restart` して、再度ログなどを観測してみてください。

Comment: 削除しました。foreman startで14:46:02 clock.1  | started with pid 18115
14:46:02 worker.1 | started with pid 18116
14:46:03 clock.1  | I, [2015-07-17T14:46:03.398240 #18115]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [ time_limit_item_check.job ]
14:46:03 clock.1  | I, [2015-07-17T14:46:03.398320 #18115]  INFO -- : Triggering 'time_limit_item_check.job'
14:46:03 worker.1 | exited with code 0
14:46:03 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
14:46:03 clock.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
エラーは出なくなりましたが、heroku psを確認するとクラッシュしています。foreman startする前はクラッシュしていません

Comment: heroku 側のログはそれで全部ですか? プロセスが起動するところから、見れると良いのですが… あと `foreman start` は、ローカルで実行するためのコマンドであって heroku で実行するためのものではないと考えていたのですが、違うのでしょうか? どういう目的で `foreman start` しているか教えてください。

Comment: すいません、どういうわけか常に=== worker (Free): `bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers`
worker.1: crashed 2015/07/17 17:20:09 (~ 16s ago)
になってしまいます。開発環境でもプロセスが入らない状態になってしまいました。ログも大量に勝手に流れています。。。上記に追加します。

Comment: foreman は、Procfile を読み込み、複数のプロセスを管理できるツール。
Heroku を動かす際にも用いられている。とqiitaの記事に書いてありました。clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rbはforemanを使って始動していました。１ヶ月ほど前に動かしたときは。。

Comment: 開発環境で `foreman start` が動かなくなったのは、先ほどProcfile
からredisのプロセスを消したためです。ローカルで実行する場合にはredisを起動する必要がありますが、herokuで実行する場合はredisccloudを使うため必要ないはずです。なおherokuで実行する場合は普通 `foreman start` する必要がありません。勝手にやってくれますので。

Comment: ログを追加しました。foremanの件承知しました。

Comment: コメント欄での説明が難しいので **2015-07-18 19:35 追記** として追記しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ダッシュボードは添付画像の状態でした。一応heroku restartしたときのログも合わせて貼りました。unicornを入れていないのですが問題でしょうか？

Comment: sidekiqのログファイルの指定を止めてみてください。herokuでは実行時にファイルを書き込めませんから、ログ用に ./log/sidekiq.log を書き込み可で開こうとしているところで落ちているようです。sidekiqは起動引数の `-L` や config/sidekiq.yml の `logfile` などでログファイルを指定しなければ標準出力にログが出力できるはずです。

Comment: ログを追加しました。heroku psで確認するとクラッシュしています。

Comment: sidekiq の起動オプションに `-d` を追加してみてください。もしくはconfig/sidekiq.yml に :daemon の追加でしょうか。
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/v3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb#L171-L173 このあたりを見るとわかるのですが、`daemon` モードでない時は `logfile` を指定しないと落ちるようになっているようです。

Comment: 現在のprocfile、sidekiq.ymlそしてログを記入しました。

Comment: ごめんなさい、逆でした。 `:daemon: false` にしてみてください。https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/v3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb#L171 この行なのですが、daemonモードでなければログファイルの指定が無くても、エラーとしないという内容でした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。プロセスが入るようになりました。調べた所carrierwave_backgrounderはherokuで使うの無理そうでした。mailerはgmailの２段階認証でキューがたまっている状況ですが、プロセスが入ったので一安心です。感謝しています。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`log` directoryが存在しないのが原因でcrashしてる様に見えます。先ずは`log` directoryをrepositoryに追加してからpushしてみて下さい。

```
cd your/project/path
mkdir -p log
touch log/.gitkeep
git add log
git commit -m 'Add log dir for sidekiq'
git push
```

Comment: 試してみましたがNo such file or directory - ./log/sidekiq.logというエラーが出ました。